# Question about the periodic potential in a crystal

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics

According to the textbooks of solid state physics, the periodic potential for an electron in a crystal should be like this in the next figure.
[image]
(Figure 2 of http://electrons.wikidot.com/energy-bands-in-solids-and-their-calculations)

In the textbook of Ashcroft and Mermin, they explain the reason for this type of curve like this,
[image]

But according to the electromagnetism, the electrostatic potential of a positive ion should be

$$ U(r)=kq/r  $$ 
so In my opinion the sign of $U(r)$ in the second picture seems to be deviates from this formula. The potential should be like this
[image]
Can anybody give me some help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's only for the minus sign for electrons, so it is switched upside down. (...and shifted, as the graph does not say where U=0 is. It is not at the axes crossing!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electrostatic potential of a positive point charge is indeed
$$
\varphi(r) = \frac{kQ}{r}
$$
and it is positive. The potential *energy* of a negative charge $-q<0$ in that potential is given by
$$
U(r) = -q\varphi(r) = -\frac{kQq}{r}
$$
and it is negative. For more details, consult any introductory electromagnetism textbook.

Comment: So, U(r) here is a energy rather than a potential. If it is a energy,  then it will make sense.

Comment: Yes, it is potential as in potential energy, not as in electrostatic potential.